# How can I get the rows with the most cells that have the highest (or the lowest) values

Tags: excel

I have a table of data which is consisted of 18 columns and 2.017 rows. I can get the row that has the highest (MAX) value in a cell but I need the row that has the most cells with higher values and have them in DESC order. I haven't managed yet to find a relevant post to this.

Here follows an example:

[image]

Using numbers up to 10 for illustration, the following shows the logic behind. (The actual numbers are those shown in Exhibit1)

[image]

Thank you

EDIT:

I am adding the below in order to try to clarify further. I am not sure if it is the correct path to go but I hope it makes sense.

In Exhibit2 I am indexing each column Desc (Based on Exhibit1) and then =SUM in the end of the row. Following this logic, the name having the lowest total is the one with the most high values (not the highest) in its row.

The result table is the following

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add a bit more explanation plz? For example, why is Dave first in the expected results?

Comment: Is your 2nd example truly representative?  In your first example, all of the names have only a single entry =MAX of that row.  Also, what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Just add a helper column with formula like `countif(theRow,max(theRow)` and sort on that.

Comment: Looks like you want to sort on the average per row. But that would make the position of jack & Jason arbitrary

Comment: For Jack & Jason, which is better 2 tens or 3 nines?

Comment: @Solar Mike For Jack and Jason, Jack is better (3 nines).  The 8 of Jason makes him go to a lower position.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am using Excel 2016 and I tried `countif(theRow,max(theRow)` this way `=countif(theRow,max(theRow))` but I get `1` in all cells of the helper column

Comment: What are the values in the cells of that row?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld `0.82, 1.68, 0.17, 3.03, 2.09, 1.68, 0.11, 1.80, 0.47, 2.07, 0.34, 4.22, 2.17, 2.45, 0.62, 0.89, 0.92, 0.52` These are the actual values

Comment: Your result is expected since only one of those cells has the highest value. That is why I asked you for clarification in my first comment about how realistic your 2nd example is. You need to clarify exactly what you want, in words.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You are correct in this, but  in my first one Ι use exhibit1 from my actual table and then in the 2nd one in order ro explain the logic behind, I use random 0-10 numbers. My mistake that I missed answering to your comment requesting to explain further above.

Comment: Had you done so, I would have asked you, as I just did above, to clarify your requirements. You write: *" I need the row that has the most cells with higher values"*. I ask you ***higher than what?***

Comment: There are 2017 rows having similar data. Getting one cell in each row with the highest value, doesn't help. I need in the top, the row that all of its cells have the highest values, not just one. Even if one or two cells in a row have very high values and another two very low it will  appear in a lower position from another row which doesn't have so high values in its cells but most of its cells have high values in general. Example is Jack and Jason. Why is Jack higher than Jason since he has 2 tens? Its because Jack doesn't have an eight.

Comment: When you are able to define in words exactly what you mean, I will be able to help you.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Please check EDIT on my original post. I hope it makes sense now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243369/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-galanopd).

Comment: @TomSharpe Please check EDIT on my original post. I hope it makes sense now

Comment: @JvdV No, the average wouldn't help in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although possible with formulas and helper tables/columns, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

  - As we discussed in our Chat, I transform each column into a list of Ranked Entries; then sum the ranks for each row and sort as you have laid out.

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],

//type all the columns
    data = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Order", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Name", type text}} &
        List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2), each {_, type number})
    ),

//Replace with ranks
//generate list of transforms to dynamically include all columns
    cols = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(data),2),
    xForms = List.Transform(cols, (c)=> {c, each List.PositionOf(List.Sort(Table.Column(data,c),Order.Descending),_)}),
    ranks = Table.TransformColumns(data,xForms),

//add Index column to enable row-wise sums
// then add the sumRank column and delete the Index column
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(ranks, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "sumRank", each 
        List.Sum(
            Record.ToList(
                Record.RemoveFields(#"Added Index"{[Index]},{"Order","Name","Index"})
            )
        )),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),

//join back with the original data table
//extract the sumRank column
    join = Table.NestedJoin(data,{"Order","Name"}, #"Removed Columns",{"Order","Name"}, "joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(join, "joined", {"sumRank"}, {"sumRank"}),

//sort by the sumRank column, then remove it
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded joined",{{"sumRank", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"sumRank"})
in  
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This set-up is `volatile`, so I would only adopt it if non-volatile alternatives are not forthcoming.

An additional column in your table with the following formula:

`=SUM(COUNTIF(OFFSET([Column1],,TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(Table1[@[Column1]:[Column4]])))-1)),">="&Table1[@[Column1]:[Column4]]))`

which you can then use to sort your table.

Note that this formula will most likely require committing with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` for your version of Excel.

Amend the table and column names as required, noting that the part

`Table1[@[Column1]:[Column4]]`

as well as including the table name, should comprise the leftmost and rightmost of the contiguous columns to be interrogated.